# Best way to serve files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, apache

I'm a novice web developer with some background in programming (mostly Python).
I'm looking for some basic advice on choosing the right technology.

I need to serve files over the internet (mp3's), but I need to implement some
control on the access: 
1. Files will be accessible only for authorized users.
2. I need to keep track on how many times a file was loaded, by whom, etc.

What might be the best technology to implement this? That is, should I
learn Apache, or maybe Django? or maybe something else? 
I'm looking for a 'pointer' in the right direction.

Thank!
R

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track/control the downloads that suggests that the MP3 urls need to be routed through a Rails controller.  Very doable.  At that point you can run your checks, track your stats, and send the file back.

If it's a lot of MP3's, you would like to not have Rails do the actual sending of the MP3 data as it's a waste of it's time and ties up an instance.  Look into xsendfile where Rails can send a response header indicating the file path to send and apache will intercept it and do the actual sending.

https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/

http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Sendfile.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use Django and Lighttpd as a web server. With Lighttpd you can use mod_secdownload, wich enables you to generate one time only urls.

More info can be found here: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModSecDownload

You can check for permissions in your Django (or any other) app and then redirect the user to this disposable URL if he passed the permission check.

Comment: @RanLevi If you end up using S3, they have this functionality (time based expiration too).

Comment: S3 as in Amazon's cloud, I guess? Great idea, Philip, I'll look into it.